# Compile code using GPU processing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, compilation, gpu

I would like to know if it's possible to compile my C# code in VS2012 using the GPU and CPU (or only GPU)?

I want to do so to optimize my compilation time since I have 3 or 4 solutions to compile everytime.

I have an ATI Radeon 5450

Comment: Pushing things to the GPU is useful *when that work fits within what the GPU can do*. I'm simply not sure that applies here... however, it should use your available CPU cores nicely already

Comment: @PLAudet I think you missed the point entirely. Planes are designed for a similar but distinctly different and separate purpose, much like GPUs. See this question (and answer) for a detailed explanation: http://superuser.com/questions/308771/why-are-we-still-using-cpus-instead-of-gpus

Comment: @tnw I totally got the point. I was just being sarcastic. If you carefully read the question. I'm asking if it's possible, if it's not just say no. I know GPU are there for another purpose but there are API (like CUDA) for this.

Comment: @PLAudet Yeah, CUDA is there for the actual processing of your application. I'm unaware of any solutions currently for compiling with the GPU.

Comment: @tnw The link you sent me is the kind of answer I was looking for. thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use GPU acceleration on compiling multiple programs on a gcc compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417053/is-it-possible-to-use-gpu-acceleration-on-compiling-multiple-programs-on-a-gcc-c)

Comment: This would depend entirely on the compiler vendor, in this case Microsoft, to implement some sort of GPU acceleration in Visual Studio. I think it's definitely the case that some improvements are possible if they'd use OpenCL, DirectX compute, C++AMP, etc. For example, the compiler could try different optimization decisions, in parallel, and assess the results. But there's nothing we can do as users to make Visual Studio smartly leverage GPUs – it has to be implemented by the Visual Studio dev team.

Comment: Just use a CPU which has internally GPU plated for example Ryzen's G Series.